# How are all serializer errors returned in DRF at once?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm testing for multiple validation errors to be raised in`(UserRegistrationSerializer)`.
Yet DRF only returns the first error that is raised:
**{'username': [ErrorDetail(string='Choose a different username', code='invalid')]}**

I'm expecting: **{'username': [ErrorDetail(string='Choose a different username', code='invalid')], 'password2': [ErrorDetail(string='Password confirmation failed', code='invalid')]**

How can multiple errors be accounted for once a serializer is validated as in the documentation example?

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

```
class TestRegisterationSerializer__002(TestCase):
    '''Verify that the registeration process fails with respect
    to selecting an unavailable username and password confirmation'''

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        User.objects.create_user(username="Python")
        cls.data = {
            'username': "Python",
            'password': "#secret#",
            'password2': "Secret"
        }
        cls.error_messages = [
            "Choose a different username", "Password confirmation failed"
        ]
        cls.serializer = UserRegisterationSerializer(data=cls.data)

    def test_user_registeration_invalid_confirmation(self):
        self.serializer.is_valid()
        print(self.serializer.errors)
```

```
import re

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework import serializers


class UsernameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    username = serializers.SlugField(min_length=4, max_length=12)

    def validate_username(self, value):
        try:
            self.Meta.model.objects.get(username__iexact=value)
        except self.Meta.model.DoesNotExist:
            return value
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Choose a different username")

    class Meta:
        fields = ['username', ]
        model = User


class LoginSerializer(UsernameSerializer):

    password = serializers.RegexField(
        r"[0-9A-Za-z]+", min_length=5, max_length=8
    )

    def validate(self, data):
        username, password = [
            input.lower() for input in [data['username'], data['password']]
        ]
        if all(password[i] == password[i + 1] for i in range(len(password) - 1)) or username == password:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({
                'password': "Invalid password"
            })
        return data

    class Meta:
        fields = ['username', 'password', ]
        model = User


class UserRegistrationSerializer(LoginSerializer):

    password2 = serializers.RegexField(
        r"[0-9A-Za-z]+", min_length=5, max_length=8, write_only=True
    )

    def validate(self, data):
        data = super().validate(data)
        if data['password'] != data['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"password2": "Password confirmation failed"})
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'password2']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the customizations of validate method  in UsernameSerializer and LoginSerializer and place this method inside UserRegistrationSerializer

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate(self, data):
    errors = []
    data = super().validate(data)
    username = data.get("username")
    if self.Meta.model.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists():
       errors.append({"username":"Choose a different username"})

    username, password = [
            input.lower() for input in [data['username'], data['password']]
        ]
    if all(password[i] == password[i + 1] for i in range(len(password) - 1)) or username == password:
        errors.append({
            'password': "Invalid password"
        })
    
    if data['password'] != data['password2']:
        errors.append({"password2": "Password confirmation failed"})

    if errors:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)
    return data
```

Comment: In django 4.0.6 the errors object needs to be a dictionary with the fields as keys in order to work properly. Perhaps a recent change? As you have, all errors would be stored in the `non_field_errors` collection, at least in my testing.

Answer (score 3):

As Krishna mentioned, you should use the validate method of the UserRegistrationSerializer - it should be in the `validate()` method rather than `validate_<param>()` methods because it is a validation across fields, rather than a validation of a single field.

However Krishna's raised error will not work using django 4.0.6 (for me, at least!) - the reason is that the `errors` object needs to be a dictionary with the fields as keys, not a list of dictionaries. Passing a list of dictionaries will cause the errors to be represented as non_field_errors.

Krishna's corrected example would then be:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...other specs ...
    def validate(self, data):
        errors = {}
        username = data.get("username")
        if self.Meta.model.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists():
           errors["username"] ="Choose a different username"

        username, password = [
            input.lower() for input in [data['username'], data['password']]
        ]
        if all(password[i] == password[i + 1] for i in range(len(password) - 1)) or username == password:
            errors['password'] = "Invalid password"
    
        if data['password'] != data['password2']:
           errors["password2"] ="Password confirmation failed"

        if errors:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)
        return data
```

This will raise the errors correctly as individual field errors in django 4.0.6